# Condição em uma lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arraylist

Tenho um programa que insere informações em um arquivo CSV. E queria verificar se há dados na variável, caso não mostrar uma mensagem que não há dados inseridos no arquivo.

```
 var csv = listForRegister.Select(l => String.Join(";", 
                                                   l.DriverName.ToString(), 
                                                   l.NationalId.ToString(),
                                                   l.InitialTime,
                                                   l.EndTime,
                                                   l.Distance.ToString() 
                                                   + " Km")).ToArray();


 if ( csv == null )
 {
     string display = "Não ha registro nesta data.";
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                        "yourMessage", 
                                        "alert('" + display + "');", true);
     Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Path);
 }
```

Comment: tente colocar seu if da seguinte maneira `if (csv == null || !csv.Any())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o `.ToArray` possui a propriedade [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx), creio que isto deva funcionar

```
if ( csv.Length == 0 )
{
    string display = "Não ha registro nesta data.";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yourMessage", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
    Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Path);
}
```